# Tooltip nested in <label>, prevent 'mousedown' triggering input:active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a specific situation where we nest tooltip in `<label>` (which we use for to implement custom radio button design).

event.preventDefault() works fine with 'click' on the tooltip but fails on 'mousedown' where it triggers `:active` state of the hidden `<input>` field. Thus changing the styling of fake radio button.

I made a small example to demonstrate what is happening.

```js
const $tooltipElement = $('.tooltip');
$tooltipElement.on('click', (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.box {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+.box {
  background: blue;
}

input:active+.box {
  background: red;
}

.text {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.tooltip:active {
  background: gray;
}

.tooltip:active::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="text">Option 1</span>
  <span class="tooltip" data-content="Message 1" tab-index="0"></span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="text">Option 2</span>
  <span class="tooltip" data-content="Message 2" tab-index="0"></span>
</label>
```

This is how it looks when holding mousedown on tooltip. Radio circle, must remain the same, but it changes to red bg color...

[image: This is how it looks when holding mousedown on tooltip]

**[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/develoger/Ljr78sLf/)**

Comment: why not just remove the active css?

Comment: Sadly we need it, the design requires it. Initially, there was no need for tooltip nested within the label and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you considered just implementing all the styling with JS? I don't think what you want will work with just :active and stuff.

Comment: Why not just move the tooltip outside the label - if I were to click on an info box, I wouldn't expect it to also check that option at the same time

Comment: We are implementing atomic design approach. Where tooltip and radio-button are 2 separate components. Which makes the scenario where we must not access radio-button from tooltip and vice versa... This makes it harder :). Also styling from JS is the last solution, I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @Pete that is a good point, I actually did it at first but it just creates another styling problems. There are situations where we have multi-line labels etc.

Comment: You could just wrap the label and the tooltip (tooltip outside label) in a new span with position relative, it would act as if the tootip where in it's current position inside the label

Comment: @Pete that is good idea. We will need additional wrapper component which we can use in this specific use-case... I will test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this: instead of putting the tooltip in the label, put it in a span the wraps the label and tooltip (moving your label styles to this span):

```js
const $tooltipElement = $('.tooltip');
$tooltipElement.on('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.box {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+.box {
  background: blue;
}

input:active+.box {
  background: red;
}

.text {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.tooltip:active {
  background: gray;
}

.tooltip:active::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="text">Option 1</span>
  </label>
  <span class="tooltip" data-content="Message 1" tab-index="0"></span>
</span>

<span class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="text">Option 2</span>
  </label>
  <span class="tooltip" data-content="Message 2" tab-index="0"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, Pete, I will test this in out environment and accept the answer if it fits :)